# Satisfying build dependencies of a stack

Tags: ros, stack, metapackage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Say I want to build from source a collection of packages united into a stack (like `navigation` or `image_pipline`). Such stacks contain multiple packages plus a meta-package named after the stack. In order to build the whole thing, it's sufficient to type e.g. `catkin_make --pkg navigation`. However, the compilation will fail if some of the packages in the stack have unsatisfied dependencies.

I would expect `rosdep install navigation` to resolve these dependencies for me (as soon as they are properly stated in package manifests), however in reality it does not do anything because the manifest of `navigation` meta-package does not contain `build_depend` tags. I wonder why it is so, and what is the right way to satisfy the dependencies of a stack without going through each package individually.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191709/satisfying-build-dependencies-of-a-stack/) by [sergey_alexandrov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1412/sergey_alexandrov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 260 on 2014-09-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosdep can be used to satisfy the build dependencies for your workspace, assuming your packages and stacks are in the `src` directory:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src -i
```

This should install the build and run dependencies for all of the packages in your workspace.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1